# Mechanical relay circuit schematic and PCB. What is wrong here?

Tags: transistors, pcb, relay, opto-isolator

I built a relay that closes when a GPIO gives a GND signal.  I have tested the circuit with a breadboard and it works with the same components (except breadboard uses THD diode and PCB uses SMD), but for some reason my PCB circuit will not close the relay.  I am monitoring the normally open circuit by wiring in a 1000 ohm resistor and LED.  When the switch closes I should hear the mechanical relay and the LED should light up.  But no luck.

I do not see any differences between my schematic and PCB but something is off.  I even swapped out core components like optocouplers, transistors, relays to be sure they weren't just dead.  There is an LED which turns on when GND signal is given at GPIO, I can turn this on/off without problems so I know this signal is present.  I have verified that I am seeing 5V from my MOSFET power supply's drain, which supplies 5V to the circuit.  Does anyone know what could be keeping my PCB from working?

[image: relay module]
[image: schematic]
[image: PCB]

Comment: Looks like your diode is backwards.

Comment: I was going to ask why is D6 there?  If it's a flyback diode, it's backward.  Otherwise it's going to limit the voltage across your coil to whatever its forward voltage is.

Comment: Backwards on PCB or schematic?  It is intended to by a flyback diode as you mentioned.

Comment: Presumably, good layout software does not even allow connecting the diode differently as per the schematic.

Comment: Yea that is true once I messed up the schematic layout/PCB was bound to mess up as well.  I am realizing the reason the breadboard probably works is that it was constructed by looking at another reference schematic, so it likely doesn't have the diode error.

Comment: @Unimportant How would the layout software "not allow" you to ignore the cathode band and insert the diode backward? I'm sure I have done this at least once.

Comment: D6 is placed reversed. It should be 180 degree rotated

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: The schematic capture can't prevent you from putting a diode in a particular direction (electrically.) The PCB layout software, however, can make you connect it the right way around (electrically) on the PCB.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Since the OP asked "backwards on PCB or schematic?", and he only posted pictures of the layout, I presumed he meant PCB layout Vs. schematic. Obviously we can't tell if it's physically installed correctly with the information given. (but I guess if it's installed the wrong way then in this case it would be correct :)

Comment: Can you measure 0v and 5v across the relay when it is off and on? If so, is your particular relay coil polarized? (Try closing it using 5v manually.)

Comment: The opto's input = (5V - 0.5V - 0.5V) / 1k ~= 4mA, which is a bit marginal. Perhaps use 470R instead of 1k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D6 is backwards on the schematic.  It is not clear from the PCB decal which end is the cathode.

Consider adding a 10K resistor from Q3 base to GND to assure a rapid and complete turn-off.

Based on typical values for the Vf of an LED and an optocoupler, it looks like there is only 1.5 mA of current through the opto primary side.  Depending on the minim coil current for the relay, this might not be enough to drive Q3 into firm saturation.

Update:  To increase the transistor's collector current, decrease R11.  A safe starting value is to determine from the datasheet the max continuous sink current for the GPIO pin, and size R11 for 1/2 of that.  Next, use the CTR (current transfer ratio) of the optocoupler to find its secondary current.

Comment: Are you suggesting to lower the resistance of R12 from 510ohms?  Or lower R11 from 1000ohms

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 1):

1. D6 is backwards in the schematic - mentioned in comments and other answers.  With it backwards, trying to activate the relay will cause a short circuit across the *5Vgreen_o* line, probably short circuiting the power to everything (including the microprocessor.)
2. The optoisolator isn't needed here.  You have both sides tied to the same power source  - there's no isolation at all.

Drop the optoisolator (along with R11 and LED D5) and have your software write a high to GPIO12 to activate the relay.

If you really **must** activate the relay with a low signal, then you can use two transistors instead of one.

---

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftb458.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your microprocessor runs on 5V, and you want to activate the relay with a low signal, then you could do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNX2qb.png)</sup>

Comment: Write a high signal to base of Q3 transistor?

Comment: Yes.  High to the base of Q3 - through a resistor.  Keep R12.

Comment: Alright I'll give this a try on the breadboard tonight

Comment: JRE makes a good point - if the only reason for the optocoupler is signal inversion, there are more simple and direct ways to do it.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion.  I wired the top diagram up and it worked great.

Comment: Yes , D 6 diode wrong direction.